# how to move from fragment to activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

now i'm in fragment activity. and now i wanna go to Activity from fragment.
Here is my code tell me ?

```
public class People extends BaseFragment implements OnClickListener {
    static String name;
    ListView listview;
    TextView et;
    public static String username;
    static public List<SuccessStoreyItem> success_list3 = new ArrayList<SuccessStoreyItem>();
    public static int people_index ;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.home,null);
        ParserResult pr = new ParserResult();
        Button b=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.home1);
        listview = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lv_home);

        et=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);

        if(ParserResult.success_list2.size() != 0){
            success_list3 = ParserResult.success_list2;
        }

        listview.setAdapter(new Adapters(success_list3 ,MainActivity.mainactivity_context));
        ParserResult.success_list2 = new ArrayList<SuccessStoreyItem>();


        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//              Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "fuck you", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Profile frg3 = new Profile();
                Bundle b3 = new Bundle();
                username = "";
                username = success_list3.get(position).getStorey_id();
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.mainactivity_context,Profile_otheruser.class);
                startActivity(i);
//              b3.putString("username", username);
//              b3.putInt("index_people", position);
                people_index = position;
                frg3.setArguments(b3);
//              ((MainActivity)getActivity()).launchNewFragment(frg3, R.id.tab2);
//              Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Name :"+name ,1).show();
            }
        });



        return view;
    }
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        //Do your stuff..

    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        setTitle(R.string.Home);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        name=et.getText().toString();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("Name", name);

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Name :"+name ,1).show();


        //((MainActivity)getActivity()).launchNewFragment(new Home2(),R.id.tab1);
    }


}
```

text is:
    tell me that my that my method (context,activity.class) , start activity(i) class method is right?

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: You possibly want to know what Activity and Fragment in Android are, how they relate, and incorporate with each other before asking such questions. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: you possibly want to execute code on the activity from the fragment which is many times over duplicated question here.  But I've answered it below.

Answer (score 0):

Fragment contains an interface.  Activity implements the interface.  This way the fragment can be used with any number of activities that implement the interface.

```
public class SettingMap extends Fragment implements OnCheckedChangeListener,
    android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {



public interface BestRidesSettingsDialogListener {
    // change the map type
    void onMapSettingsChange(int mapType);
}
```

**somewhere in the fragment safely check the activity has implemented the interface and then execute code on the activity**

```
    Activity a = getActivity();
    BestRidesSettingsDialogListener activity = (BestRidesSettingsDialogListener.class.isAssignableFrom(a
            .getClass())) ? (BestRidesSettingsDialogListener) a : null;
    if (activity != null) {
        activity.onMapSettingsChange(mapType);
    }
```

**Activity implements the interface**

```
public class KmlReader extends ActionBarActivity implements
    BestRidesFollowDialogListener {


@Override
public void onMapSettingsChange(int mapType) {
    if (mMap != null) {
        mMap.setMapType(mapType);
    }
}
```

Comment: do u know about fragmentpager , pageradapter?

Comment: Yes I have one tip for the fragmentpager adapter for onActivityResult.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment/27087414#27087414